# rsync secure configuration running as daemon

Tags: rsync

The uid is set to nobody (which should be default anyway), chroot and read only are both enabled. The rsync service is being started over /etc/init.d/rsync. This is the full rsrync.conf:

```
motd file = /etc/rsync/rsyncd.motd
max connections = 4
timeout = 30
uid = nobody
use chroot = true
address = my-ip

[ubuntu-releases]
   path = /usr/share/nginx/example.com/cdn/ubuntu-releases
   log file = /etc/rsync/rsync.log
   read only = true
   list = true
```

So my question is, if this is secure or did I miss anything?

I heard about rsync over ssh but I am not sure if this is only for private access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean with secure. It's not encrypted, so susceptible to traffic sniffing. It is 'secure' in the sense that, barring rsync bugs, users only have access to what's in `/usr/share/nginx/example.com/cdn/ubuntu-releases`

Comment: Thank you, yes I should have better explained what I mean by secure. And another short question: What does the string inside the [] brackets relate to?

Comment: That's the name of the exported rsync module. It doesn't need need to match the directory name.